# Copy properties to a Builder with BeanUtils.copyProperties provided by Spring

Tags: java, spring, apache-commons, builder, lombok

I'm trying to copy properties of a POJO object to a *Builder* of another immutable object, like this:

```
public class CopyTest {

    // the source object
    public static class Pojo1 {
        private int value;

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    // the target object
    public static class Pojo2 {
        private final int value;

        public Pojo2(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public static Pojo2Builder builder() {
            return new Pojo2Builder();
        }

        // builder of the target object, maybe generated by lombok
        public static class Pojo2Builder {
            private int value;

            private Pojo2Builder() {}

            public Pojo2Builder value(int value) {
                this.value = value;
                return this;
            }

            public Pojo2 build() {
                return new Pojo2(value);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pojo1 src = new Pojo1();
        src.setValue(1);

        Pojo2.Pojo2Builder builder = Pojo2.builder();

        // this won't work, provided by spring-beans
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(src, builder);

        Pojo2 target = builder.build();
    }

}
```

The problem is : `BeanUtils.copyProperties()` provided by `spring-beans` won't call `Pojo2Builder.value(int)` because it's not a `setter`;

Besides the *Builder* class is usually generated by [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) so I can't name the method `Pojo2Builder.value(int)` as `Pojo2Builder.setValue(int)`.

By the way, I've already made it using `BeanUtilsBean.copyProperties()` in `commons-beanutils` provided by apache commons by registering a customized `BeanIntrospector`, but I found copying properties using `commons-beanutils` much more expensive than that using `spring-beans` when the copy happens between two **different** classes, so I prefer to do this using `spring-beans`

So is it possible to copy properties to a *Builder* class with Spring or some other utilities which are more efficient than `commons-beanutils`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need not only change the method name, but also to change its return type to `void` (quite stupid for a builder). Adding a `@Setter` annotation would help, [if it was allowed](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/731#issuecomment-121403049).

If you needed to copy the values into a builder of the same class, then you could use Lombok's `toBuilder()`. Or create the object directly using `@Wither`.

If you need to stick with bean conventions, then you're probably out of luck. consider using [mapstruct](http://mapstruct.org), which should be more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

If the builder doesn't follow bean conventions, then it's not going to work with bean utilities.

Either change the builder, or write your own copy utility.